# Will static linking on one unix distribution work but not another?

Tags: g++, unix

If I statically link an executable in ubuntu, is there any chance that that executable won't work within another distribution such as mint os? or fedora? I know processor types are affected, but other then that is there anything else I have to be wary of? Sorry if this is a dumb question.  Thanks for any help

Comment: Nice question. Something I thought about today.

Comment: By "unix", are you sure you didn't mean "linux"?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few corner cases, but for the most part, you should be in good shape with static linking.  The one that comes to mind is libnss.  This particular library is essentially impossible to link statically, because of the way it does its job (permissions, authentication, security tasks).  As long as the glibc-versions are similar, you should be ok on this issue, though.

If your program needs to work with subtle features of the kernel, like volume managers, you've got a pretty slim chance of getting your program to work, statically linked, across distros, because the kernel interfaces may change slightly.

Most typical applications, the kind that even makes sense to discuss portability, like network services, gui-applications, language tools (like compilers/interpreters) wont have a problem with any of this.

Comment: Newer glibc's will warn you if you statically link any of the "problem" functions. To find complete list, you could do "stings -a /usr/lib/libc.a | grep 'in statically linked applications'". This gives me 73 functions on Fedora 9. DO NOT ignore this warning, or you will crash and burn!.

Answer (score 3):

If you statically link a program on one computer and then move it to another computer in which the system basically runs the same way, then it should work just fine. That's the point of static linking; that there are no other files the program depends on - it's entirely self-contained, so as long as it can run at all, it will run the same way it does on its "host" system.

This contrasts with dynamic linking, in which the program incorporates elements of other files (libraries) at runtime. If you move a dynamically linked program to another system where the libraries it depends on are different (or nonexistent), it won't work.

Comment: This is the wrong answer, especially so on Linux. If this answer "wins", then stackoverflow is pointless :-(

Comment: I misspoke, when I wrote "architecture" I had in mind more than just chip architecture. I reworded it to make that a little better.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, your executable will work just fine.  As long as your executable doesn't depend on anything unusual being present for it to function, there will be no problem.  (And, if it does depend on something unusual being present, then you'll have the same issue even if you dynamically link.)

Statically linking is usually safer than dynamically linking for compatibility between different UNIX environments, as long as the same CPU is in use.

To have a statically linked binary fail, again assuming the same processor architecture, you would have to do something such as link on a system using the a.out binary format and try to execute it on a system running ELF, in which case the dynamically linked version would fail just as badly.

So why do people *not* routinely link statically?  Two reasons:

- It makes the executable larger, sometimes MUCH larger, and
- If bugs in the libraries are fixed, you'll have to relink your program to get access to the bug fixes.  If a critical security bug is fixed in the libraries, you have to relink and redistribute your exe.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary.  Whatever your chances are of getting a binary to work across distributions or even OSes, those chances are maximized by static linking.  Static linking makes an executable self-contained in terms of libraries.  It can still go wrong if it tries to read a file that's not there on another system.

For even better chances of portability, try linking against dietlibc or some other libc.  [An article at Linux Journal](http://m.linuxjournal.com/article/9940) mentions some candidates.   A smaller, simpler libc is less likely to depend on things in the filesystem that differ from distro to distro.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that using a smaller libc is often a good choice.  Particularly if you use a lot of facilities since glibc is quite huge you'll get huge binaries.

Answer (score 1):

There are two compatibility questions at issue here: library versions and library inventory.

You don't say what libraries you are using.

If you have no '-l' options, then the only 'library' is glibc itself, which serves as the interface to the kernel. Glibc versions are upward compatible. If you link on a glibc 2.x system you can run on a glibc 2.y, for y > x. The developers make a firm commitment to this.

If you have -l options, static linking is always safe. If you are dynamically linked, you have to ensure that (1) the library is present on the target system, and (2) has a compatible version. Your Mileage Might Vary as to whether the target distro has what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would, for the reasons noted above avoid statically linking something unless you absolutely **must**.

That being said, it should work on any other similar kernel of the same architecture (i.e. if you statically link on a machine running linux 2.4.x , the loader VDSO is going to be different on linux 2.6, VDSO being virtual dynamic shared object, a shared object that the kernel exposes to every process containing loader code).

Other pitfalls include things in /etc not being where you'd think, logs being in different places, system utilities being absent or different (ubuntu uses update-rc.d, RHEL uses chkconfig), etc.

There are sometimes that you just have no choice. I was writing a program that talked to LVM2's string based cmdlib interface in favor of using execv().. low and behold, 30% of the distros I needed to support did NOT include that library and offered no way of getting it. So, I had to link against the static object when producing binary packages.

If you are using glibc, you can be confident that stuff like getpwnam() and friends will still work .. just make sure to watch any hard coded paths (better yet, make them configurable at run time)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can guarantee it'll only be executed on a similar version of the OS on similar hardware your program will work fine if it statically linked.  so, if you build for a 2.6 Linux and statically link you will be fine to run on (almost) all 2.6 Linux distributions.

Be warned you can't statically link some parts of GLIBC so if you're using them you'll have to dynamically link anyway.  From memory the name service stuff (nss) parts required dynamic linking when I was investigating it.

You can't statically link a program for (say) Linux then expect it to run on BSD or Windows.  BSD and Unix don't present or handle their system calls in the same way Linux does.  I tell a slight lie because the BSDs have a Linux emulation layer that can be enabled, but out of the box it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not work. Static linking for distribution independence is a concept from the old unix ages and is not recommended. By the fact you can't as many libraries are not avail as static libraries anyway.

Follow the Linux Standard Base way, this is your only chance to get as much cross distribution portability as possible.

The LSB also works fine if you program for FreeBSD and Solaris.